# Why isn't all the weight of the model updated?

Tags: python, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, gradient, tensor

I'm making a model that predicts grades. It is a model that calculates with RNN using the value calculated through mathematical modeling. However, from the weight used for mathematical modeling to the weight of RNN, everything has not been updated. As a result of checking, the gradients of each weight are all being output as None.

I wonder why the weight isn't being updated.

This code is modified.

```
class Expector(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers):
    super(Expector, self).__init__()

    self.weight_0 = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor([0.2]))
    self.weight_1 = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor([0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5])) #homeownership weight
    self.weight_2 = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor([0.5 for i in range(0, 13)])) #loan_purpose weight

    #interesst_rate_expector
    self.num_features = 13
    self.linear_1 = torch.nn.Linear(self.num_features, self.num_features*2)
    self.linear_2 = torch.nn.Linear(self.num_features*2, self.num_features*4)
    self.linear_3 = torch.nn.Linear(self.num_features*4, self.num_features*8)
    self.linear_out = torch.nn.Linear(self.num_features*8, 1)

    #loan_rating_expector
    self.rnn = nn.RNN(input_size=input_size, hidden_size=hidden_size, num_layers=num_layers, batch_first=True)
    self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, input_size)

  def interest_rate_expector(self, x):
    x = [x[i] for i in range(len(x)-1)]
    for i in [0,4,9,10,11]:
      if x[i] > 0:
        x[i] = math.log(x[i])
    input = torch.tensor(x).to(DEVICE)
    out1 = self.linear_1(input)
    out1 = torch.nn.functional.softplus(out1)
    out2 = self.linear_2(out1)
    out2 = torch.nn.functional.softplus(out2)
    out3 = self.linear_3(out2)
    out3 = torch.nn.functional.softplus(out3)
    logits = self.linear_out(out3)
    interest_rate = torch.sigmoid(logits)

    return interest_rate

  def mathematical_modeling(self, x):
    salary = x[4] / 12 if x[4] != 0 else 300000
    debt = x[4] * (1 / x[5]) if x[5] != 0 else 0
  
    interest_rate = float(self.interest_rate_expector(x))

    if x[2] > 4:
        repayment = (x[0] * interest_rate * ((1 + interest_rate) ** x[1])) / ((1 + interest_rate) ** x[1]) - 1
        result = (debt * self.weight_0[0] + repayment) / (salary * x[3])
    else:
        result = (debt * self.weight_0[0] + x[0] * x[1]) / (salary * x[3])

    return torch.tensor(result)

  def forward(self, x):
    x[3] = torch.matmul(one_hot_encoding1(x[3]), self.weight_1.view(-1, 1))
    x[7] = torch.matmul(one_hot_encoding2(x[7]), self.weight_2.view(-1, 1))

    tensor = torch.tensor([x[6], x[7], x[8], x[10], x[11], x[12], self.mathematical_modeling(x)])

    tensor = tensor.unsqueeze(0)
    output, _ = self.rnn(tensor.to(DEVICE))
    final_output = self.fc(output)
    output_probabilities = F.softmax(final_output, dim=1)
    
    return output_probabilities
```

1. I have explicitly set requests_grad=True.
2. The mathematical_modeling function attempted to return the tensor.
3. I've adjusted the learning rate.

Despite these efforts, the gradient is not updated, and when I check, I only see the phrase Gradient of sensor: None. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a lot of weird stuff here that breaks the gradient chain.

When you call `.item()` on a tensor, you convert it to a scalar python value, which removes any gradient tracking.

Adding `tensor.requires_grad_(True)` only tracks gradients from that point onward. Since you computed that tensor by calling `.item()` at various points, there's no way for the gradient to propagate back.

Also the gradient isn't computed until you call `.backward()` on your loss, so no matter what your statement `print("Gradient of tensor:", tensor.grad)` in the forward pass will always return `None`.

Overall, it looks like your model is doing feature engineering within the model itself (ie the `salary` and `debt` calculations) in addition to the actual modeling part. You want to separate these.

An additional minor point, it looks like your model is creating a fixed length vector (`tensor = torch.tensor([x[6], x[7], x[8], x[10], x[11], x[12], self.mathematical_modeling(x).item()])`). If that is the case, there is no need to use a RNN, you can just use a MLP.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I made modifications to my code based on your suggestions, specifically avoiding the use of 'item()'. However, the gradients are still None. I have included the modified version of the code on this page. Could you please review my code and make any necessary corrections?

Comment: As a result of checking, backpropagation is being done properly up to RNN. However, for some weights in RNN, gradient is being calculated as zero.